# Why are there two 'KEEP' statements in this linker script section for the initialization array?

Tags: linker, startup

I am currently working with a linker script and I noticed that there are two 'KEEP' statements in a specific section for the initialization array. The section looks like this:

```
.init_array     :
{
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
  KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
  KEEP (*(.init_array ))
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
} > ram
```

I am wondering why both of these 'KEEP' statements are necessary?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.